# OAuth2 Web API 2 authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm learning how to secure a test API that I'm building and I want to implement security where a user signs up and then he requests an API Key which he will use in his app to authenticate to my API.

I started to implement this: https://github.com/vchatterji/OAuth2ClientCredentialGrant and I got the first part working where a user can signup and then request and receive a ConsumerKey & ConsumerSecret which is saved in an Azure table.

My problem is that I'm not sure what Flow I'm using The documentation doesn't state to change anything in StartupAuth:

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
          app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new    PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

I'm trying to authenticate with Fiddler and have tried many different requests but my most common error is unsupported grant type.

Based on what I have here what kind of grant type should I use?
Above it says to authenticate at /Token but other docs say api/token, which is the correct one?

Any help with composing the auth request would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for not having the data sent in the body of the request... Like this:

```html
POST http://localhost:60543/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60543
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 54
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: 85363928-a3d6-f9ad-c368-ab6019027a02
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,fr;q=0.8,pt-PT;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,es;q=0.2

username=peter&password=123456&grant_type=password
```

Make sure to set the content type in the header of the request.